# Retaining cancellable from objective-c class swift extension

Tags: swift, objective-c, combine

I have a bit of a strange situation. I'm working on a project that contains a lot of legacy objective-c code. We are working on migrating to swift, but in the meantime are relying a bit on using swift class extensions to get the ball rolling. I'm looking for a way to store a cancellable on the extended objective-c class, but I can't access `AnyCancellable` from objective-c land. This function, declared within the class extension in swift, creates a few notification observers. They need to be retained in memory so long as the class itself is.

How would I go about adding a class property to objective-c that I can use to store the cancellable in? I tried creating a sort of proxy class like this:

```swift
@objc class CancellablesHolder: NSObject {
    var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []
}
```

and declaring a property in the objc class header like so:

```objectivec
@property (nonatomic, strong) CancellablesHolder *cancellablesHolder;
```

But Xcode throws a `failed to emit precompiled header`. Is there a better way?

Would creating an `NSMutableArray` on the objective-c class and simply doing `array.add(publisher.sink {...})` suffice, or is there a better way I'm not seeing?

Comment: You're likely out of luck because `AnyCancellable` does not have an Objective-C counterpart and will not be exposed to the ObjC runtime.

Comment: It seems to be working with the `NSMutableArray` approach. It's being stored in memory but it feels hacky.

Comment: The bottom line is that Swift includes quite a few constructs that Objective-C does not understand. When exposing Swift classes/structs/protocols to Objective-C, you have to limit yourself to types that Objective-C understands. As Vym says, `AnyCancellable` is not a type that the Objective-C runtime understands. Your hack of just using an NSArray might be your best bet.

Comment: Unfortunate but this works for now. Hopefully we can prioritize reimplementing this class in swift. Thanks for your input guys

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved it by writing a wrapper class that Swift exposes to Objective-C:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

@objc final class MyCancellable: NSObject {
    let cancellable: AnyCancellable
    
    init(cancellable: AnyCancellable)
    {
        self.cancellable = cancellable
    }
    
    @objc func cancel() {
        self.cancellable.cancel()
    }
}
```

It's a Obj-C friendly box that hides a Swift `AnyCancellable` inside of it.  Then you can pass these around in Obj-C and even cancel them from Obj-C if you like.